# Use multiple versions without reinstalling

Tags: java, raspberry-pi, minecraft-forge

I was setting up a modded Minecraft server on my Raspberry Pi when I ran into an issue with forge. I had previously set up a vanilla server running 1.17 on it, which requires Java 16, but I need Java 15 or lower for forge. I previously installed the Java 16 JDK from https://adoptopenjdk.net/releases.html for arm32 architecture, which runs perfectly fine. The forge version I am trying to install a server for is 1.16.5. I downloaded the installer and it ran just fine. It generated `forge-1.16.5-36.2.2.jar`, which I am pretty sure is the server file. The problem occurs whenever I try to run that server jar file. I get the error:

```
[15:26:15] [main/INFO] [cp.mo.mo.Launcher/MODLAUNCHER]: ModLauncher running: args [--gameDir, ., --launchTarget, fmlserver, --fml.forgeVersion, 36.2.2, --fml.mcpVersion, 20210115.111550, --fml.mcVersion, 1.16.5, --fml.forgeGroup, net.minecraftforge]
[15:26:15] [main/INFO] [cp.mo.mo.Launcher/MODLAUNCHER]: ModLauncher 8.0.9+86+master.3cf110c starting: java version 16.0.1 by AdoptOpenJDK
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class cpw.mods.modlauncher.SecureJarHandler (in unnamed module @0x1c911a1) cannot access class sun.security.util.ManifestEntryVerifier (in module java.base) because module java.base does not export sun.security.util to unnamed module @0x1c911a1
    at cpw.mods.modlauncher.SecureJarHandler.lambda$static$1(SecureJarHandler.java:41)
    at cpw.mods.modlauncher.api.LamdbaExceptionUtils.uncheck(LamdbaExceptionUtils.java:95)
    at cpw.mods.modlauncher.SecureJarHandler.<clinit>(SecureJarHandler.java:41)
    at cpw.mods.modlauncher.Launcher.lambda$new$6(Launcher.java:55)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1708)
    at cpw.mods.modlauncher.api.TypesafeMap.computeIfAbsent(TypesafeMap.java:52)
    at cpw.mods.modlauncher.api.TypesafeMap.computeIfAbsent(TypesafeMap.java:47)
    at cpw.mods.modlauncher.Environment.computePropertyIfAbsent(Environment.java:62)
    at cpw.mods.modlauncher.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:55)
    at cpw.mods.modlauncher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:66)
    at net.minecraftforge.server.ServerMain$Runner.runLauncher(ServerMain.java:63)
    at net.minecraftforge.server.ServerMain$Runner.access$100(ServerMain.java:60)
    at net.minecraftforge.server.ServerMain.main(ServerMain.java:57)
```

After researching this error message, I found that most said that the only way to fix this was to downgrade to Java 15. I really don't want to do this since I have a 1.17 server running as well, which requires Java 16 to run, so I wont be able to run it if I downgrade. I wanted to know if there was a way to work around this limitation where I could run a forge server and a vanilla 1.17 server on the same device. I will add some extra information down below which might be helpful.

Device: `Raspberry Pi 4B`

Exact JDK file: [OpenJDK16U-jdk_arm_linux_hotspot_16.0.1_9.tar.gz](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk16-binaries/releases/download/jdk-16.0.1%2B9/OpenJDK16U-jdk_arm_linux_hotspot_16.0.1_9.tar.gz)

Rapberry Pi architecture: `arm32`

Device OS: `Raspberry Pi OS Lite` (no window/display manager)

Comment: If you cannot `export JAVA_HOME` prior to starting minecraft executable, then Docker is another option for sandboxing the runtimes

Comment: There is one main problem with using docker. I am using MineOS to manage the servers with a webgui, I need both of the servers to be able to be managed through MineOS. I don't think that I could manage the servers through MineOS if it is within a docker container. Doing `export JAVA_HOME` probably wouldn't work either because of MineOS.

Comment: I'm not really familiar with MineOS, but assuming it is interacting over HTTP or other TCP socket channel, then it "_should work_" with a bit of networking configuration

Answer (score 0):

If you install both versions, you should be able to specify which version to use by first typing

```
ls /usr/lib/jvm/
```

This will list all versions you have installed. For me it shows java-16-openjdk and java-8-openjdk. Now you want to edit your server start file and in the begging put `/usr/bin/jvm/javaversion/bin/java`, for example `/usr/bin/jvm/java-16-openjdk/bin/java -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -jar forge-1.16.5-36.2.2.jar`. In some versions the path is `/usr/bin/jvm/javaversion/jre/bin/java`.